# Dynamic seeding in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm extremely new to laravel and having trouble with this seeder. I feel like it should be an easy thing to do, I just don't have the right tools for it yet.

I need to populate a column with data based on a different column. More specifically, I want to take the `employee_id`, find where their location is in the employee table, and populate that id in the application table. This is what I have so far:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Employee;
use App\Application;


class ApplicationEmployeeLocationTableSeeder extends Seeder 
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $applications= Application::all();

        foreach ($applications as $application)
        {
            $location_id = Employee::whereId($application->employee_id)->pluck('location_id')->first();
        }

    }

}
```

This returns all the ids I'm looking for as a string, but how do I put these values into `location_id`in the applications table? Running this seeder doesn't produce an error, but it doesn't do anything either.

Let me know if there's any other information you need, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you just pulled the `location_id` from an object.  Also, to eliminate multiple hits to the database in that loop, I suggest you pull in a collection of employees (pulling from the DB only once) before the loop, and then find the right location for the employee from the collection.

The way you have it now, you go to the DB on every looped application to draw an employee.  Having a collection before the loop will eliminate all those pulls.

I'll break it out into a few steps below for clarity, but you can tighten this if you wish:

```
$applications= Application::all();
$employees = Employee::all();

foreach ($applications as $application)
{
    $emp = $employees->where('id', $application->id)->first()
    $location_id = $emp->location_id;
}
```

To put the location for the application back into the database, you can simply save it to the application object:

```
foreach ($applications as $application)
{
    $emp = $employees->where('id', $application->id)->first()
    $location_id = $emp->location_id;
    $application->location_id = $location_id;
    $application->save();
}
```

The above is writing to the DB each time, which I was trying to avoid, but once you get this working, you can always investigate adding those applications to a collection and then saving the collection.  But this should get you where you want to be.